# How to use the Google Sign In access token instead of authorization code for getting the data from the Google Search Console?

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-signin, google-search-console, oauth2client

I want to access the listed websites data in the Google Search Console using the Google Sign-In access_token (that one can get as the response when using Google Sign-In).

But, the thing is I can access that data only by using the `authorization_code` that can be copied from the `OAuth2-Consent` screen by going to the generated `authorize_url` and signing in using the registered Google account.

Here's the **minimum reproducible version** of the code:

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build

CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly'
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

print ('Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url)
code = input('Enter verification code: ').strip()

credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
        
webmasters_service = build('webmasters', 'v3', http=http)

def get_property_list(webmasters_service):
    '''
    Get a list of validated properties from GSC
    '''
    site_list = webmasters_service.sites().list().execute()
 
    # Filter for verified websites
    verified_sites_urls = [s['siteUrl'] for s in site_list['siteEntry']
                        if s['permissionLevel'] != 'siteUnverifiedUser'
                            and s['siteUrl'][:4] == 'http']
    return verified_sites_urls
        
        
print({"available_websites": get_property_list(webmasters_service)})
```

Consider that I'll be provided with the Google Sign-In access-token as the request-parameter from another server which has implemented Google Sign-In feature.

So, again my question is how can I access the same data using that token instead of manually getting the auth_code from the OAuth2 consent screen ?

Comment: Your not accessing the data using the authorization_code  the client library is exchanging the authorization_code  for an access token for you.    Btw sign in is authentication or open id connect you get an id token.    Oauth2 is authorization granting access to data this uses an access token.   [Understanding Oauth2 with curl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w)

Comment: Try looking at this it might help https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/access_from_python

Comment: Hello @DaImTo, 

Thanks for the response.

Can you please tell me how can I use the access-token directly to access the data ?

Comment: Again the code you have is already doing that.  check whats in credentials why dont you should have an access token in there once the exchange is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/access_from_python) shared by [DaImTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) in the comments above. And modified the code as shown below:

---

```
from oauth2client.client import  OAuth2WebServerFlow
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client import tools, file

CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly'
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

# Acquire and store oauth token.
storage = file.Storage('token.json')
credentials = storage.get()

if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
        
webmasters_service = build('webmasters', 'v3', http=http)

def get_property_list(webmasters_service):
    '''
    Get a list of validated properties from GSC
    '''
    site_list = webmasters_service.sites().list().execute()
 
    # Filter for verified websites
    verified_sites_urls = [s['siteUrl'] for s in site_list['siteEntry']
                        if s['permissionLevel'] != 'siteUnverifiedUser'
                            and s['siteUrl'][:4] == 'http']
    return verified_sites_urls

print({"available_websites": get_property_list(webmasters_service)})
```

---

It's working fine now, without any manual interaction for copying and pasting the `authorization_code` from the `OAuth2-Consent` screen.